# What is wrong with this list comprehension code?

Tags: haskell

My aim is to list all elements of the array `a` whose values are greater than their index positions. I wrote a Haskell code like this.

```
[a|i<-[0..2],a<-[1..3],a!!i>i]
```

When tested on ghci prelude prompt, I get the following error message which I am unable to understand.

`No instance for (Num [a]) arising from the literal 3 at <interactive>:1:20 Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Num [a])`

Comment: the minimal edit: ``[a!!i|i<-[0..2],a<-[[1..3]],a!!i>i]``.

Comment: another one: ``[a|i<-[0..2],a<-[[1..3]!!i],a>i]``. :)

Comment: This is an identity function. Given an ordered list it will produce the very same list as the result. That is, given [1..3] will produce [1,2,3]. There are other way to achieve list identity, [1..3] is one, enumFromTo 1 3 is another. [1..3]!!0 is 1, [1..3]!!1 is 2, [1..3]!!2 is 3.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Given the expression `a!!i`, Haskell will infer that `a` is a list (i.e. `a::[a]`). Given the expression `a<-[1..3]`, Haskell will infer that `a` will have type `Num a => a` (because you are drawing `a` from a list of `Num a => a` values). Trying to unify these types, Haskell concludes that `a` must actually be of type `Num a => [a]`.

The bottom line is that it doesn't make sense to treat `a` as a list in one context and as an element from a list of numbers in another context.

**EDIT**

I'm thinking you could do what you want with something like this:

```
f xs = map fst . filter (uncurry (>)) $ (xs `zip` [0..])
```

The expression `` xs `zip` [0..] `` creates a list of pairs, where the first value in each pair is drawn from `xs` and the second value from `[0..]` (an infinite list starting from 0). This serves to associate an index to each value in `xs`. The expression `uncurry (>)` converts the `<` operator into a function that works on pairs. So the expression `filter (uncurry (>))` filters a list of pairs to only those elements where the first value is greater than the second. Finally, `map fst` applies the `fst` function to each pair of values and returns the result as a list (the `fst` function returns the first value of a pair).

**EDIT 2**

Writing pointless code is fun, and so I give you:

```
f = map snd . filter (uncurry (<)) . zip [0..]
```

Comment: Thanks and I understand the error. The immediate question is how to correct this?

Comment: How to correct it depends on what your intention is with this code.

Comment: @augustss my intention, as mentioned in my post, is to list elements of a list which are greater than the index positions.

Comment: @suresh: If you prefer list comprehensions, use `[x | (i, x) <- zip [0..] xs, x > i]`. I think that's slightly clearer than the solutions above.

Comment: @hammar I'm inclined to agree. Your version is more comprehensible. Why not submit that as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

```
import Data.Maybe
import Control.Monad

f = catMaybes . zipWith (mfilter.(<)) [0..] . map Just
```

Disclaimer: The given code was not proof read and may have been made outside of sobriety. The author has little recollection of what it is about.